Database object not created. how create it better way
class Database {

    private $dbHost = 'localhost';
    private $dbUser = 'root';
    private $dbPass = 'usbw';
    private $dbName = 'track_serial';
    private $db;

    public function __construct() {
       // Here generate undefined variable $db
        $this->$db = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->dbHost . ";dbname=" . $this->dbName, $this->dbUser, $this->dbPass);
    }

    public function getData($sql) {
        $stmt = $this->$db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $data = $stmt->fetchAll();
        return $data;
    }
}

It is generate error as
Undefined variable $db (2)
#0 D:\MAHINDA\Portable App\usbwebserver\root\trackserial\models\database.php(14): flight\Engine->handleError(2, 'Undefined varia...', 'D:\MAHINDA\Port...', 14)

And where is the code that should create that variable $db?

You have to write $this->db, not $this->$db.  Look more carefully at the examples in the documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php
